# Convert ShaderToy to fragment shader

Tags: android, iphone, opengl-es, fragment-shader

I came across several shaders on ShaderToy and I have not had success converting them into a format that can be used on a mobile device, such as a `.fsh`.

I have [this](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ldjGzV) Shader, and I want to be able to use it on a mobile device.

I know that I need to make modifications to the iXXXX variables and change mainImage to main().

Does anyone know how I can do this? I am unable to find any resources on how to do this, and have never encountered it myself.

```
float noise(vec2 p)
{
    float sample = texture2D(iChannel1,vec2(1.,2.*cos(iGlobalTime))*iGlobalTime*8. + p*1.).x;
    sample *= sample;
    return sample;
}

float onOff(float a, float b, float c)
{
    return step(c, sin(iGlobalTime + a*cos(iGlobalTime*b)));
}

float ramp(float y, float start, float end)
{
    float inside = step(start,y) - step(end,y);
    float fact = (y-start)/(end-start)*inside;
    return (1.-fact) * inside;

}

float stripes(vec2 uv)
{

    float noi = noise(uv*vec2(0.5,1.) + vec2(1.,3.));
    return ramp(mod(uv.y*4. + iGlobalTime/2.+sin(iGlobalTime + sin(iGlobalTime*0.63)),1.),0.5,0.6)*noi;
}

vec3 getVideo(vec2 uv)
{
    vec2 look = uv;
    float window = 1./(1.+20.*(look.y-mod(iGlobalTime/4.,1.))*(look.y-mod(iGlobalTime/4.,1.)));
    look.x = look.x + sin(look.y*10. + iGlobalTime)/50.*onOff(4.,4.,.3)*(1.+cos(iGlobalTime*80.))*window;
    float vShift = 0.4*onOff(2.,3.,.9)*(sin(iGlobalTime)*sin(iGlobalTime*20.) + 
                                         (0.5 + 0.1*sin(iGlobalTime*200.)*cos(iGlobalTime)));
    look.y = mod(look.y + vShift, 1.);
    vec3 video = vec3(texture2D(iChannel0,look));
    return video;
}

vec2 screenDistort(vec2 uv)
{
    uv -= vec2(.5,.5);
    uv = uv*1.2*(1./1.2+2.*uv.x*uv.x*uv.y*uv.y);
    uv += vec2(.5,.5);
    return uv;
}

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    uv = screenDistort(uv);
    vec3 video = getVideo(uv);
    float vigAmt = 3.+.3*sin(iGlobalTime + 5.*cos(iGlobalTime*5.));
    float vignette = (1.-vigAmt*(uv.y-.5)*(uv.y-.5))*(1.-vigAmt*(uv.x-.5)*(uv.x-.5));

    video += stripes(uv);
    video += noise(uv*2.)/2.;
    video *= vignette;
    video *= (12.+mod(uv.y*30.+iGlobalTime,1.))/13.;

    fragColor = vec4(video,1.0);
}
```

Comment: what problem are you facing exactly while converting  ?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I just don't know how to do it, I need to use it on an iOS device, however ShaderToy adds some extra stuff that isn't needed on other platforms.

Comment: the shader is written in GLSL (however, you didn't list the uniforms they are using in your question). Are you getting compile errors when trying it on iOS? Perhaps you should post those...?

Answer (score 5):

I've written `main()` and included the Sprite equivalent variables of the ShaderToys variables at the bottom of my answer.

**Setup**

To apply a shader to your node you need to tell SpriteKit to attach a shader to the SKSpriteNode in the `.fsh` file.

1. Create empty text file ending in `.fsh` for the shader code.

The swizzle

**shader1.fsh**

```
void main() {

vec4 val = texture2D(_texture, v_tex_coord);
vec4 grad = texture2D(u_gradient, v_tex_coord);

if (val.a < 0.1 && grad.r < 1.0 && grad.a > 0.8) {
vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_sprite_size.xy;
uv = screenDistort(uv);
vec3 video = getVideo(uv);
float vigAmt = 3.+.3*sin(u_time + 5.*cos(u_time*5.));
float vignette = (1.-vigAmt*(uv.y-5)*(uv.y-5.))*(1.-vigAmt*(uv.x-.5)*(uv.x-.5));

video += stripes(uv);
video += noise(uv*2.)/2.;
video *= vignette;
video *= (12.+mod(uv.y*30.+u_time,1.))/13.;

gl_FragColor = vec4(video,1.0);

} else {
 gl_FragColor = val;
}

} // end of main()
```

2. Next, attach the shader in SpriteKit.

**shader1.swift**

```
let sprite = self.childNodeWithName("targetSprite") as! SKSpriteNode
let shader = SKShader(fileNamed: "shader1.fsh")
sprite.shader = shader
```

### Explanation

- The shader turns every pixel the color of the effect (screenDistort(uv)).
- main() is the entry point.
- gl_FragColor is the return.
- For each pixel of the image this code is executed.
- When the code executes it is telling each pixel that the color should be the color of the effect. The vec4() call has a r,g,b,a values.

**ShaderToys variable names ->  SpriteKit variable names**

`iGlobalTime` -> `u_time`

`iResolution` -> `u_sprite_size`

`fragCoord.xy` -> `gl_FragCoord.xy`

`iChannelX` -> `SKUniform with name of “iChannelX” containing SKTexture`

`fragColor` -> `gl_FragColor`

Since you have the Sprite equivalent variables you can now easily convert these remaining methods that are above `main()`.

`float noise {}`

`float onOff {}`

`float ramp {}`

`float stripes {}`

`vec3 getVideo {}`

`vec2 screenDistort {}`

### Theory

Q. Why does `main()` contain `texture2D` and `u_gradient, v_tex_coord`?

A. SpriteKit uses textures and uv coordinates.

**UV mapping**

UV mapping is the 3D modeling process of projecting a 2D image to a 3D model's surface for texture mapping.

**UV coordinates**

When texturing a mesh, you need a way to tell to OpenGL which part of the image has to be used for each triangle. This is done with UV coordinates. Each vertex can have, on top of its position, a couple of floats, U and V. These coordinates are used to access and distort the texture.

[SKShader Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShader_Ref/index.html)

[OpenGL ES for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/opengl-es/)

[Best Practices for Shaders](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/BestPracticesforShaders/BestPracticesforShaders.html)

[WWDC Session 606 - What's New in SpriteKit - Shaders, Lighters, Shadows](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/606/)

Answer (score 0):

this works for me in unity3D engine.

```
// Upgrade NOTE: replaced 'mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,*)' with 'UnityObjectToClipPos(*)'


Shader"ShaderMan/Clip"{
Properties{
_MainTex("MainTex", 2D) = "white"{}
_SecondTex("_SecondTex",2D) = "white"{}
}
SubShader{
Pass{
CGPROGRAM
#pragma vertex vert
#pragma fragment frag
#pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
#include "UnityCG.cginc"
struct appdata{
float4 vertex : POSITION;
float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
};
uniform sampler2D  _MainTex;
uniform fixed4     fragColor;
uniform fixed      iChannelTime[4];// channel playback time (in seconds)
uniform fixed3     iChannelResolution[4];// channel resolution (in pixels)
uniform fixed4     iMouse;// mouse pixel coords. xy: current (if MLB down), zw: click
uniform fixed4     iDate;// (year, month, day, time in seconds)
uniform fixed      iSampleRate;// sound sample rate (i.e., 44100)
sampler2D _SecondTex;

struct v2f
{
float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
float4 screenCoord : TEXCOORD1;
};

v2f vert(appdata v)
{
v2f o;
o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
o.uv = v.uv;
o.screenCoord.xy = ComputeScreenPos(o.vertex);
return o;
}
fixed noise(fixed2 p)
{
    fixed sample = tex2D(_SecondTex,fixed2(1.,2.*cos(_Time.y))*_Time.y*8. + p*1.).x;
    sample  = mul(    sample ,sample);
    return sample;
}

fixed onOff(fixed a, fixed b, fixed c)
{
    return step(c, sin(_Time.y + a*cos(_Time.y*b)));
}

fixed ramp(fixed y, fixed start, fixed end)
{
    fixed inside = step(start,y) - step(end,y);
    fixed fact = (y-start)/(end-start)*inside;
    return (1.-fact) * inside;

}

fixed stripes(fixed2 uv)
{

    fixed noi = noise(uv*fixed2(0.5,1.) + fixed2(1.,3.));
    return ramp(fmod(uv.y*4. + _Time.y/2.+sin(_Time.y + sin(_Time.y*0.63)),1.),0.5,0.6)*noi;
}

fixed3 getVideo(fixed2 uv)
{
    fixed2 look = uv;
    fixed window = 1./(1.+20.*(look.y-fmod(_Time.y/4.,1.))*(look.y-fmod(_Time.y/4.,1.)));
    look.x = look.x + sin(look.y*10. + _Time.y)/50.*onOff(4.,4.,.3)*(1.+cos(_Time.y*80.))*window;
    fixed vShift = 0.4*onOff(2.,3.,.9)*(sin(_Time.y)*sin(_Time.y*20.) + 
                                         (0.5 + 0.1*sin(_Time.y*200.)*cos(_Time.y)));
    look.y = fmod(look.y + vShift, 1.);
    fixed3 video = fixed3(tex2D(_MainTex,look).xyz);
    return video;
}

fixed2 screenDistort(fixed2 uv)
{
    uv -= fixed2(.5,.5);
    uv = uv*1.2*(1./1.2+2.*uv.x*uv.x*uv.y*uv.y);
    uv += fixed2(.5,.5);
    return uv;
}

fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target{

{
    fixed2 uv = i.uv;
    uv = screenDistort(uv);
    fixed3 video = getVideo(uv);
    fixed vigAmt = 3.+.3*sin(_Time.y + 5.*cos(_Time.y*5.));
    fixed vignette = (1.-vigAmt*(uv.y-.5)*(uv.y-.5))*(1.-vigAmt*(uv.x-.5)*(uv.x-.5));

    video += stripes(uv);
    video += noise(uv*2.)/2.;
    video  = mul(    video ,vignette);
    video  = mul(    video ,(12.+fmod(uv.y*30.+_Time.y,1.))/13.);

    return  fixed4(video,1.0);
}
}ENDCG
}
}
}
```